# serialzie c# object to json array with different types

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have trouble to convert an c# object so an json array.

```
    public class ChartValue
    {        
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public float Value { get; set; }
    }
```

This object should be serialized like this for example:

```
[
   "2020-03-03T13:27:45",
    52.2
]
```

I need to stick to this json structure so adjusting is not possible.
For serializian the Newtonsoft.json class is used.

Using a string array failed for me because the value is then "52.2" which is not accepted.
Any ideas how to adjust the serialization or to create a "multitype" array

thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new object[] { chartValue.Timestamp, chartValue.Value });`?

Comment: You can do this with a custom `JsonConverter` for `ChartValue`.  For a manual solution see [JSON deserialization - Map array indices to properties with JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36760064/3744182).  For an automatic solution using reflection see [How to deserialize objects containing arrays of values with a fixed schema to strongly typed data classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39462464/3744182).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51637335/366064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is a build in way, but you can write your own `JsonConverter` using some reflection magic:

```
public class ChartValueToArrayJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(ChartValue);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
                                    Type objectType,
                                    object existingValue,
                                    JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer,
                                   object value,
                                   JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null) return;

        writer.WriteStartArray();

        var properties = value.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
            writer.WriteValue(value.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(value));

        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ChartValue(), new ChartValueToArrayJsonConverter()) // results in ["0001-01-01T00:00:00",0.0]
```

or mark your `ChartValue` class with `[JsonConverterAttribute(typeof(ChartValueToArrayJsonConverter))]` attribute if you want this behavior globally.